# Get name used to fire event within handler in JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is my JavaScript code.:

```
//Events to watch
CanvasIO.events = [
    "object:added",
    "object:removed",
    "object:modified",
    "object:rotating",
    "object:scaling",
    "object:moving"
];

//Socket connection
CanvasIO.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

//Canvas events fired
for (e in CanvasIO.events) {
    CanvasManager.canvas.on(e, function(data){
        CanvasIO.socket.emit("canvas:event", {
            eventType: e,
            data: data
        });
    });
}

//Socket IO event received
CanvasIO.socket.on("canvas:event", function(data) {
    console.log("Received: " + data.eventType);
});
```

My problem is that in the Canvas Event Fired part I wish to generate automatic messages to be emitted based on the events name. But because I use `eventType: e` every message will get the last state of `e`, `"object:moving"`.

So, for:

```
CanvasManager.canvas.on(key, handler)
```

Would it be possible to access the `key` within the `handler`? If not, how should I proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on but one guess is that your for loop should definitely be `for(var e in CanvasIO.events)` and not how you have it.  You're defining a global e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that as your for loop keeps iterating, the value of `e` inside your handler is updating too. To get around this function you can wrap the handler in a function to which you pass `e` (this is called a 'closure'). It works by creating a new scope for your event variable, and thus is unchanged as the for loop increments, or you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (I believe)

```
for (e in CanvasIO.events) {
    CanvasManager.canvas.on(e, function(event){
        return function(data){
            CanvasIO.socket.emit("canvas:event", {
                eventType: event,
                data: data
            });
        };
    }(e));
}
```

or

```
for (e in CanvasIO.events) {
    CanvasManager.canvas.on(e, function(event, data){
        CanvasIO.socket.emit("canvas:event", {
            eventType: event,
            data: data
        });
    }.bind(null, e));
}
```

This is a pretty annoying problem that comes up all the time, here's some more info: [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly. I just had to replace `e` with `CanvasIO.events[e]`